# I need DRY validate function to make its shorter

Tags: javascript, function, dry

I have a validation function were is some code is repeating, how I can make it more shorter.

```
function validated() {
  if (user.value.length < 9) {
    user.style.border = '1px solid red';
    userError.style.display = 'block';
    user.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (password.value.length < 9) {
    password.style.border = '1px solid red';
    passError.style.display = 'block';
    password.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: By creating a function to do the repeated work

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateField(elt, errorElt, minLength) {
  if (elt.value.length < minLength) {
    elt.style.border = '1px solid red';
    errorElt.style.display = 'block';
    elt.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validated() {
  return validateField(user, userError, 9) && validateField(password, passwordError, 9);
}
```

Comment: so, this is nice example, but for me its not working correctly. so idea is that still input don't have correct amount of symbols, you can't login. you code allow fill one in go inside

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).